# Changing the discriminate-column in a single table sub class with JPA inheritance

Tags: java, orm, jpa, domain-driven-design

I have a domain model that looks like this:

```
     Instruction
       |      \
     Money    Other
     /   \ 
   Unit Cash
```

and I want to map this model to my DB using JPA.

All classes map to the same table in the DB, (T_INSTRUCTION).

So I started out with jpa's SINGLE_TABLE inhertance strategy. Separating the `Money` and `Other` classes using the orm xml `discriminate-column="MONEY_TYPE_ID"`.

My problem is I also want to sperate the sub classes `Cash` and `Unit`
but they discriminate on a different column "`CASH_TYPE_ID`".

Scanning the docs this doesn't seem possible to me, but I was wondering does anyone out there have any tricks or workarounds to implement this?

Cheers

Comment: So what is the expect result at the end? 2 discriminator columns?

Comment: Yeah, I essentially want to use 2 different discriminator columns in the object hierarchy.

Comment: Who needs the CASH_TYPE_ID exactly? What should the MONEY_TYPE_ID contain in that case? Could you show some example records to illustrate the constraints (for the other apps), this might help to find an acceptable working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having looked into this a little futher, there is no solution to this problem in the current JSR spec.

So what I decided to do in the end, was to use jpa single table inheritance for the '`Instruction`' '`Money`' and '`Other`' types and then to allow '`Cash`' and `'Unit'` sub types of simple inhert from these. (i.e) `'discriminate-column="MONEY_TYPE_ID"'`

Then use the constructor in the 'cash' and 'unit' to set field that maps to `CASH_TYPE_ID`.

PS: I'll post the code later

Answer (score 1):

A workaround may be to have different discriminator values for each subclass, and only one discriminator column. i.e. money=1, other=2, unit=3, cash=4

Comment: Yeah that would work, but unfortunately the table is shared with other apps, so cant change its structure. cheers